# NHIbernate Load via QBE with single column PK

Tags: nhibernate

When invoking Session.Load where the class in question contains a composite id, Load expectes the provided criteria to be an example of the object in question with all the PK properties filled in. The problem is that I want to create a generic IRepository interface with a single Load method, always providing a QBE. However, it seems that Load can not handle QBE if the PK is only a single property. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [repository interfaces](http://github.com/codai/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/src/SharpArch/SharpArch.Core/PersistenceSupport/IRepository.cs) in the [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/downloads.htm) project. They expose two interfaces that allow for a standard integer id as well as another other type (eg. your composite key object) to be specified for `Get` and `Load` operations. This is probably the route I would take in your case.